# modelling question regarding smooth curved and flat surfaces

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

im fairly new to 3d modelling and im having trouble in getting the smooth curves and flat surfaces I want on a watch strap ive designed. attached are two picture, the first showing the 3d model in blender (that has shading problems and harsh edges) and a rough drawing of what im aiming to achieve. thank you for your time. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Ive already attempted using a subsurface modifier and the strap is already shaded smooth.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe show a picture with the 3 views: top, side, right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's what you want but here is a try. Begin with a UV Sphere, etc... You could also use this sphere to boolean a rectangle...

[image]

Comment: this actually did help very much. thank you for your quick response :)